# My shadows aren't rendering in EEVEE but working perfectly in the viewport

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine, shadows

I've been modeling and working on this scene for days a couple of bumps on the road but I've been doing pretty good. I've never had problems with shadows, and I've checked every possible forum. It's shadows a enabled and everything everybody mentioned is enabled I think. Maybe I'm missing something.  I shared the picture below red is rendered and green is my viewport display

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should share your blend file to take a look at it